# Why is my python program not running the code in the right order?

Tags: python

I just started out in python and I am programming a hangman game base on a book. May I know why is my code below not running in the order that I want it to run?

When I execute the program, the letter guessed in `guess` is suppose to go into `used` to indicate which letters has the player already guessed to find out the right word. However, this only happens every 2 turns and not every 1 turn. I've indicated the hangman ACSII art at the start of the program in an image file for reference, below the image are the code. Would gladly appreciate any help. Thanks!

[image]

```
MAX_WRONG = len(HANGMAN)-1

WORDS = ("book","toy","paper","school","house","computer","television")
word=random.choice(WORDS)
so_far = "-"*len(word)
wrong = 0
used = []

print "Welcome to hangman! Guess the the word before the the man is hang      dead!"
print "You can only guess one letter at a time!"

while wrong < MAX_WRONG and so_far!=word:
    print HANGMAN[wrong]
    print "\nYou've used the following letters:\n",used
    print "\nSo far, the word is:\n", so_far
    guess = raw_input("\n\nEnter your guess:")
    guess = guess.lower()

    if guess in word:
        used+=guess
        print "\nYou've used the following letters:\n",used
        print"\nYes!",guess,"is in the word!"
        new=""
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                new+=guess
            else:
                new+=so_far[i]
        so_far=new

    else:
        used+=guess
        print "\nYou've used the following letters:\n",used
        print "\nSo far, the word is:\n", so_far
        print"\nSorry,",guess,"isn't in the word."
        guess = raw_input("\n\nEnter your guess:")
        wrong+=1

    while guess in used:
        print "You've already guessed the letter:",guess
        print "\nYou've used the following letters:\n",used
        print "\nSo far, the word is:\n", so_far
        guess = raw_input("Enter your guess:")
        guess = guess.lower

if wrong == MAX_WRONG:
    print HANGMAN[wrong]
    print "\nYou've been hanged!"
else:
    print "\nYou guessed it!"

print "\nThe word was",word

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: Step through your code in a debugger, or use a rubber duck to help! Clearly your code is being executed in the order you wrote it, you just didn't write it in the order you THINK you did!

Comment: If you are wondering why your post got negative votes, it is most likely because you posted your entire program. In general, people like you to spend more time on your own to find where the bug is inside your program. If you take the time to narrow it down to a small section that you know isn't doing what you think it should then you will often find the bug on your own.

Comment: @skyler I see, i will do that the next time round! Noted with thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be happening 2 turns, but that is not the case. The problem is that your program prompts the user twice in a single turn. At the start of the loop you ask the user for a letter. If it was tell me it was wrong, then you ask for another letter. Then your loop repeats and you ask for a letter again.

The problem is that you are asking for a letter twice within the loop, not once. In programming we have what is called the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) which means don't repeat yourself. Your code shows one of many reasons not to repeat yourself. You thought that your loop was running twice, but you were actually just running the same code multiple times in your loop.